# Samba Shares Without Using Winbind

Tags: samba, kerberos, server-message-block, winbind, sssd

I am curious if it is possible to use samba shares without using winbind. In our current environment we are using SSSD, Kerberos, and Samba to complete the required tasks such as joining the windows domain and setting up active directory/LDAP.  Since we are using SSSD instead of winbind how can we setup a samba share for the Windows machines to access using the current implementation?  I can share some of the configuration as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using domain or ads [you are out of luck](https://www.samba.org/samba/history/samba-4.8.0.html):

> Domain member setups require winbindd
>
> Setups with "security = domain" or "security = ads" require a
> running 'winbindd' now. The fallback that smbd directly contacts
> domain controllers is gone.

You will need to [use winbind to join the domain](https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2018-June/216630.html) in any other case.